# mobile device only shows 80% of page's width

Tags: html, screen, media, footer

I uploaded a responsive site I did for a friend that does not render full width on the Index Page whether viewed on a smartphone or tablet.

*The lady is doing me a favor as I try to get my name and work known. She has a business she'd like to see grow and we thought the Internet the place to start.*

The odd thing is that site's other pages render just fine with proper width and height.

This leads me to believe the problem is with the "@media screen" queries.

I believed the CSS "width" and other properites and values in the full width, non-mobile page's code, would "cascade" down into the smaller mobile queries but added the properties "head," "html, body" and "footer" sections to see if that would improve the situation.

It did not.

The site can be viewed here: [www.notaryonwheelsshaver.com](http://www.notaryonwheelsshaver.com/)

The CSS can be read here: http://www.notaryonwheelsshaver.com/css/nows.css

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first media query (780px) has a typo in `html,body` -> `height: 100%x;` That may be interfering with the `min-width` attribute under it.

I don't know if that will fix it, but it's what I noticed.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Sometimes a guy just needs someone else to look things over. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your CSS file:

```
    html, body {
        font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 26px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        color: #555;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        /*width: 100%;*/
    }
```

`/*width: 100%;*/` is commented out which makes the browser skip the code try changing it to:

```
    html, body {
        font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 26px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        color: #555;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

EDIT: You have the width also commented in:

```
.wrapper {
        /*min-width: 100%;*/
        min-height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I read another post where a guy said that since html, body are inherently 100% width, the properties were unnecessary. I took out the width values and viola! The page rendered properly. Thanks for replying, another set of peepers is always helpful after staring at the project for days, you just miss stuff.